# For each unique value in a column1 find the maximum value in Column3 and the corresponding value in Column3 using excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, hstack

Let's say we have a dataframe in Sheet 1 of the workbook and the desired output in sheet 2 is to return the maximum value in `Var3` for each unique value in Var1 and the corresponding value in Var2.

**Dataframe:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

The code below only gives the maximum value of all values as shown below:

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(INDEX(Sheet1!B2:C19,,MATCH(E1,Sheet1!C1,0)),CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!A2:C19,1),CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!A2:C19,2)),1,-1),5)
```

[image]

Comment: I have one question is the user input is for only `Var2` & `Var3` or will be there more columns?, also is it a typo `MATCH(E1,Sheet1!C1,0)` where `E1` refers to `User Input` where as the cell `F1` reads as `Var3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, INDEX(A2:C19,,XMATCH(J1,A1:C1)),
     CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:C19,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(a,MAXIFS(a,A2:A19,UNIQUE(A2:A19))))),{1,3,2}))
```

---

Comment: In case the order of unique values is not in ascending order and is random, how can we change the formula to get V1 unique values in ascending order

Comment: @vp_050 wait i will update, basically you need the same output, but the data is not in ascending order and is random right?

Comment: Yes. that's correct

Comment: @vp_050 but what i found even if its not sorted and is random then also it would work, however in this case the return output where the `Var1` column indexed as first one will be random, you can sort the output data

Comment: Can this sorting be acheived within the formula?

Comment: @vp_050 yeah like this the output is sorted here try this one and let me know : `=LET(
a,INDEX(A2:C19,,XMATCH(J1,A1:C1)),SORT(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:C19,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(a,MAXIFS(a,A2:A19,UNIQUE(A2:A19))))),{1,3,2})))` same formula only the output is sorted.